# The request was denied because one or more scopes requested are unauthorized or expired

Tags: email, microsoft-graph-api

I am going through the sample code from https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample
and when clicking the Mail link I get this error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qh9sp.png) I have set up the Azure AD following the instructions and set the permissions. (2.jpg) but am still receiving the same error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXXOQ.png)

Comment: You need to give admin consent by clicking on `Grant Admin Consent for Joyce Organization`

Comment: Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: What @ShivaKeshavVarma  said is right, you need to grant `admin consent` for permissions. https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoHj8.png

Comment: If my answer is helpful please accept it by checking the check mark so that it can be helpful to others you face similar issue. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give admin consent by clicking on `Grant Admin Consent for Joyce Organization`.

[image]

You can go through this [Admin-restricted permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#admin-restricted-permissions) for more information.